# Using maven-deploy-plugin to deploy Eclipse product

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, tycho

I am trying to deploy an Eclipse product to Nexus repository. I am somewhat successful, but still get some errors that I am not sure how to handle.

I am using maven-deploy-plugin in the feature (F) that builds product:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy-file</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <repositoryId>snapshots</repositoryId>
                        <packaging>zip</packaging>
                        <generatePom>true</generatePom>
                        <url>http://repo:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
                        <groupId>my.group</groupId>
                        <artifactId>my.artifact</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                        <file>
                            target/products/product.zip
                        </file>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I execute 'mvn clean install' to build the product and then 'mvn deploy' on F. If I do that then I get error

`Exception while publishing product /home/akravets/dev/workspaces/trunk/my.repository.feature/myProduct.product: publishing result: [Included element my.product.feature.feature.group 8.0.1.R20180301-1431 is missing. Cannot determine filter for requirement to this element.] -> [Help 1]`

I've read discussions about this issue, but nothing seems relevant to my issue because I don't have any defined deploy phases besides the one in maven-deploy-plugin.

If I change phase of maven-deploy-plugin to 'install' I get almost satisfactory results. The zip file and generated pom get deployed to repository, but the build fails with error

```
product.qualifier-p2artifacts.xml. Return code is: 400, ReasonPhrase: Bad Request.
```

Why does this file even gets considered to be deployed to repository when it's not in file element of maven-deploy-plugin and it's not in the directory structure where zip file is: target/ vs target/product/product.zip? Is this because maven-deploy-plugin is executed during the install phase and it picks up all generated resources as candidates for deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply recommend you to use Maven-Tycho to deploy Eclipse RCP product.Tycho determines the dependencies of a plug-in via the MANIFEST.MF file of the plug-in and fetches the required plugins-bundles through the online repositories.

You can check this git repository as an example; [rcp - tycho](https://github.com/sparsick/tycho-eclipse-rcp-example)